# How to Unhide column A in Excel and Google Doc?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-docs

Let's say I hide column A in excel or in google doc, how can I unhide it (show column A again).
Column A is the most left column. I have column B,C and D etc...

Comment: In Excel, left-click on the column B header and drag left. Then right-click and choose Unhide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, if a column is hidden, the separator line between the column headers is a bit more pronounced, i.e. thicker. To unhide column A, hover over the dark line next to the column B header, right-click an select "Unhide".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, on Google Docs you have little > mark to click on and expand hidden colums.
On LibreOffice you can click on the first header to mark all columns and rows and than click on Format/Row(Column)/Show.
I personally don't use excel so I'm guessing it's same as this second example

Answer (score 0):

You can actually select column `B` and the column with the numbers, then right click and select Unhide.

Click and hold on column `B` and drag your mouse to the left and you'll have selected `B` and the column with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

On Google Docs, there's a small triangle in the column to the right (in this case Column B) to unhide. However, if Column B is frozen, then this triangle will be disabled. In this case, select from the menu *View* -> *Freeze Columns* -> *No frozen columns*. After that, the triangle will be enabled again.

(courtesy of [this post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/e0a0lzTvCRg))

Answer (score 0):

This should really be separated as Excel and G-Sheets are quite different in so many respects, it's not useful to combine them for specific questions like this.

G-Sheets: I was concerned about unhiding the A through C columns in a spreadsheet I've been working on. As I don't know about an interactive code feature as I do in Excel (VBA 'immediate' section), I looked online for an answer, as I often do rather than fumbling around wasting my time looking for a best way when someone else has already found it and taken the time to tell us about it. But to no avail! So, I personally unearthed the following way to unhide the leftmost unclickable (i.e. hidden) columns in G-Sheets, which turns out to be very simple, albeit not obvious to me until I actually saw it. So w/o further ado, here it is:

1. click on the down-arrow in the header of leftmost visible column (displays the drop-down context sensitive menu) and select "Unhide columns"
2. as the result from step 1 does not scroll leftwards to reveal the now unhidden columns, you'll need to do so in order to see it actually worked.